# Load data from XML file to SQL database in Azure using Logic Apps

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm new to Azure development, and I'm having trouble finding examples of what I want to do.
I have an XML file in Azure file storage and I want to use a Logic App to get that XML data into a SQL database.

I guess I will need to create a "SQL Database" in Azure, before the Logic App can be written (correct?).
Assuming that I have some destination SQL database, are there Logic App connectors/triggers/whatever that I can use to:  1) recognize that a file has been uploaded to Azure, and 2) process that XML to go into a database?
If so, can such connectors/triggers/whatevers be configured/written so that any business rules I have, for massaging the data between the XML and the database, can be specified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right you need to create the db and then write logicapps to perform necessary functionality.

There are lot of connectors with trigger like blob storage, Sql connector etc...
You can perform your processing with the help of "[Enterprise Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-xml)" or you can do custom processing using "**AzureFunctions**" which integrate with logic apps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform CRUD operations on an Azure SQL Database, you can use the SQL Connector. Documentation on the connector can be found here: 
[Logic App SQL Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/)
[Adding SQL Connector to a Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure)

I've also written a blog myself on how to use the SQL Connector to perform Bulk operations using a stored procedure and OpenJSON : [Bulk insert into SQL](http://integration.team/2017/05/26/logic-apps-sql-server-bulk-inserts-using-openjson/)

This might help you in designing your Logic App if you choose to use a stored procedure.