# Loading (large) XML data into Azure SQL database table

Tags: xml, t-sql, xml-parsing, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I have been working on a solution for transferring a large XML file into Azure SQL database, thus far unsuccessfully. The XML file is accessed via a fixed URL. I have no previous experience using SQL or Azure before this project, so I apologise if I've missed something obvious.

I setup the database with appropriate tables, I just need to populate the tables with my data.

The XML file comes in the following format, however there are several thousand jobs. The file, when downloaded, is approximately 1.2Mb however I want to access it from the URL not local computer.

```
<Response api-method="Current">
  <Status>OK</Status>
     <Jobs>
        <Job>
           <ID>N1234</ID>
           <Name>Job name here</Name>
           <Description/>Job description here</Description
           <StartDate>2018-10-08T00:00:00</StartDate>
           <DueDate>2018-10-21T00:00:00</DueDate>
           <Manager>
              <ID>12345</ID>
              <Name>John Smith</Name>
           </Manager>
        </Job>
        <Job>
            Repeat above several thousand times
        </Job>
     </Jobs>
</Response>
```

So far my most successful method works using some built-in Azure Logic Apps. I am using HTML GET to load the XML data, then passing it into the Liquid app which converts XML into JSON. I then expect JSON format can be easily loaded into a database table. This Logic App successfully converts the XML to JSON, but only when I strip the file down to ~80 jobs. Hence I know that my logic app works and that the file size is my issue.

[XML to JSON Logic App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq6ic.png)

Does anyone have a suggestion for a better approach or a method of allowing larger files to be processed? I have also tried using SSMS, implementing T-SQL BulkInsert, OpenRowSet, etc but I've abandoned this approach for the time being.

Small selection of sources I've used while trying to find a solution:

- [How can I to read a XML from a URL using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054652/how-can-i-to-read-a-xml-from-a-url-using-t-sql)
- [Load data from XML file to SQL database in Azure using Logic Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044916/load-data-from-xml-file-to-sql-database-in-azure-using-logic-apps)
- Countless MVA videos

Many thanks

Comment: you should have a look at azure data factory, it will be a better fit for what youve explained

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I was planning on using data factory once the data was in JSON format since data factory cannot handle XML as far as I could tell.

Comment: MitchW - pls let me know how did you get the XML data from API

Comment: Which Action and trigger did you choose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience on *how do I load an XML from an URL via Azure SQL Server*. In *normal* SQL-Server there are some weird approaches, but I'd recommend do read the URL from another application.
But - as you managed to load the file somehow - this does not seem to be your issue anyway.

Why do you feel the need to convert this to `JSON`? SQL-Server can deal with native XML pretty well. The standard transfer format is `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, which is an `UCS-2`-string, which is almost the same as `UTF-16` or simple `2-byte-unicode`. Any `.Net`-string can be sent to SQL-Server *as is*. The size limit of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is big enough for your needs...

Just create a function like the following and call it via your reading application. You can pass the parameter as a string:

This function will accept a *2-byte_encoded* unicode string and convert this to XML implicitly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ReadTheXml(@xml XML)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT @xml.value('(/Response/Status/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Response_Status
          ,job.value('(ID/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Job_ID
          ,job.value('(Name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Job_Name
          ,job.value('(Description/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Job_Description
          ,job.value('(StartDate/text())[1]','datetime') AS Job_StartDate
          ,job.value('(DueDate/text())[1]','datetime') AS Job_DueDate
          ,job.value('(Manager/ID/text())[1]','int') AS Job_Manager_ID
          ,job.value('(Manager/Name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Job_Manager_Name
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Response/Jobs/Job') A(job)
GO
```

--Assuming you've got the XML loaded into a string already you can test it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX) =         --the xml as NVARCHAR(MAX) string
N'<Response api-method="Current">
  <Status>OK</Status>
     <Jobs>
        <Job>
           <ID>N1234</ID>
           <Name>Job name here</Name>
           <Description>Job description here</Description>
           <StartDate>2018-10-08T00:00:00</StartDate>
           <DueDate>2018-10-21T00:00:00</DueDate>
           <Manager>
              <ID>12345</ID>
              <Name>John Smith</Name>
           </Manager>
        </Job>
        <Job>
           <ID>blah</ID>
           <Name>One more</Name>
           <Description>This is one more description</Description>
           <StartDate>2018-10-08T00:00:00</StartDate>
           <DueDate>2018-10-21T00:00:00</DueDate>
           <Manager>
              <ID>12345</ID>
              <Name>John Smith</Name>
           </Manager>
        </Job>
     </Jobs>
</Response>';
```

--Use the function exactly the same way as you'd use a table:

```
SELECT * INTO #tmpStagingTable 
FROM dbo.ReadTheXml(@xml); --pass in the XML as string

--call the result from the staging table
SELECT * FROM #tmpStagingTable;  --create a staging table *on the fly*
GO

--clean up for testing
DROP FUNCTION dbo.ReadTheXml;
DROP TABLE #tmpStagingTable;
```

The result should be inserted into a staging table. Do any needed cleansing and business logic against this staging table and proceed from there.

The result

```
+-----------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| Response_Status | Job_ID | Job_Name      | Job_Description              | Job_StartDate           | Job_DueDate             | Job_Manager_ID | Job_Manager_Name |
+-----------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| OK              | N1234  | Job name here | Job description here         | 2018-10-08 00:00:00.000 | 2018-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 12345          | John Smith       |
+-----------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| OK              | blah   | One more      | This is one more description | 2018-10-08 00:00:00.000 | 2018-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 12345          | John Smith       |
+-----------------+--------+---------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you Shnugo, this is exactly what I needed. Simple yet effective, appreciate your help.